# Stored procedure using cursors dramatically slow

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

I wrote a stored procedure that sometimes i need to call many times in a row. The sp uses one cursor. It is the first time I realize why Robert Vieira wrote "Cursors are slow" in his SS2000 Pro book i read years ago.

Could you suggest a better implementation?
I am sorry to use copy and paste and not to use a simplified version, anyway a general suggestion is fine too I don't expect you to rewrite it.

here the code:

```
CREATE  PROC sp_DuplicaDocDistrib(@ID_DIP_SRC INT ,@ID_DIP_DEST int) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID_LISTA INT
    DECLARE @ID_DISTRIB INT
    DECLARE @TIPO_DISTRIB NVARCHAR(1)
    DECLARE @NRO_COPIE NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @NOTE NVARCHAR(50)

    SET @ID_LISTA  = (SELECT LAST_ID FROM SW9_SEQUENCES WHERE SEQ_NAME ='DOCN_ID_LISTA_DISTRIBUZIONE') 
       SET @NOTE  = 'Automatically distributed on  '+  convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 103) 

    DECLARE CURSOR_DOCDISTRIB CURSOR FOR    
       SELECT ID_DISTRIBUZIONE,TIPO_DISTRIBUZIONE,NRO_COPIE from DOC_LISTE_DISTRIBUZIONE BASE
       WHERE BASE.ID_DIPENDENTE = @ID_DIP_SRC
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ID_LISTA FROM DOC_LISTE_DISTRIBUZIONE
         WHERE ID_DISTRIBUZIONE = BASE.ID_DISTRIBUZIONE AND ID_DIPENDENTE = @ID_DIP_DEST)

      OPEN CURSOR_DOCDISTRIB
      FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_DOCDISTRIB INTO @ID_DISTRIB,@TIPO_DISTRIB,@NRO_COPIE

      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      BEGIN
        SET @ID_LISTA = @ID_LISTA +1
        PRINT @ID_LISTA
        PRINT @ID_DISTRIB
        INSERT INTO DOC_LISTE_DISTRIBUZIONE (ID_LISTA,ID_DISTRIBUZIONE,ID_DIPENDENTE,NRO_COPIE,TIPO_DISTRIBUZIONE,NOTE)
           VALUES (@ID_LISTA,@ID_DISTRIB,@ID_DIP_DEST,@NRO_COPIE,@TIPO_DISTRIB,@NOTE)

        FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_DOCDISTRIB INTO @ID_DISTRIB,@TIPO_DISTRIB,@NRO_COPIE        
      END
      CLOSE CURSOR_DOCDISTRIB
      DEALLOCATE CURSOR_DOCDISTRIB

      UPDATE SW9_SEQUENCES
            SET LAST_ID = @ID_LISTA
            WHERE SEQ_NAME = 'DOCN_ID_LISTA_DISTRIBUZIONE'    

END
```

Comment: have you tried change your cursor declaration into a `join` structure and filter on non-null values instead of a `not exists` clause?

Comment: @adrin: Seems this doesn't need a `cursor` at all.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: yeah saw the answers. Seems in this case it's not needed.

Comment: Is `ID_LISTA` in `DOC_LISTE_DISTRIBUZIONE` an IDENTITY column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FAST_FORWARD cursors (it's a shorthand for static, forward_only, read-only), they're much faster than defaults.

However, I believe that you don't need a cursor here at all, it could be rewritten as a simple INSERT.. SELECT FROM.

Comment: Amazing! FAST_FORWARD: the keyword who saved the day!

Answer (score 2):

Seems you can avoid the cursor here

Please replace your cursor with statement like below.. I haven't put all the columns here but sure you get the idea!!

```
INSERT INTO DOC_LISTE_DISTRIBUZIONE (ID_LISTA,ID_DISTRIBUZIONE,ID_DIPENDENTE,NRO_COPIE,TIPO_DISTRIBUZIONE,NOTE)
SELECT @ID_LISTA,ID_DISTRIBUZIONE, @ID_DIP_DEST, TIPO_DISTRIBUZIONE,NRO_COPIE 
From DOC_LISTE_DISTRIBUZIONE BASE
WHERE BASE.ID_DIPENDENTE = @ID_DIP_SRC
         AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ID_LISTA FROM DOC_LISTE_DISTRIBUZIONE
         WHERE ID_DISTRIBUZIONE = BASE.ID_DISTRIBUZIONE AND ID_DIPENDENTE = @ID_DIP_DEST
```

Read more about  [Insert Data From One Table to Another Table](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/)

If you need incremental field, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to achieve this.

i.e.

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() Over (order By FieldName1) IncrementField ,FieldName2
From TableName
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact i was looking for a way to get rid of the cursor. I'll try your approach.

Comment: i realize i need a cursor because I need to manually assign the IDs, since they are not autogenerated. This is why i opted for cursor (notice the `SET @ID_LISTA = @ID_LISTA +1`)

Comment: @user193655:To use incremental field... I have update my answer!! Please refer

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `ID_LISTA` is not an IDENTITY column, meaning you will need to populate this manually.

You are declaring your cursor as:

```
   SELECT ID_DISTRIBUZIONE,TIPO_DISTRIBUZIONE,NRO_COPIE from DOC_LISTE_DISTRIBUZIONE BASE
       WHERE BASE.ID_DIPENDENTE = @ID_DIP_SRC
         AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT ID_LISTA FROM DOC_LISTE_DISTRIBUZIONE
             WHERE ID_DISTRIBUZIONE = BASE.ID_DISTRIBUZIONE AND ID_DIPENDENTE = @ID_DIP_DEST
         )
```

However, when you loop through your cursor, the only processing you appear to be doing is to increment the value of `@ID_LISTA`. One solution therefore may be to start off creating a temporary table:

```
  CREATE TABLE #Temp (
     ID_LISTA_INC int IDENTITY(1,1),
     ID_DISTRIBUZIONE ...,
     ID_DIPENDENTE ...
     (etc)
  )
```

Then,

```
  INSERT INTO #Temp
       (ID_DISTRIBUZIONE, ID_DIPENDENTE, ...)
       SELECT ID_DISTRIBUZIONE,TIPO_DISTRIBUZIONE,NRO_COPIE from DOC_LISTE_DISTRIBUZIONE BASE
           WHERE BASE.ID_DIPENDENTE = @ID_DIP_SRC
             AND NOT EXISTS (
                 SELECT ID_LISTA FROM DOC_LISTE_DISTRIBUZIONE
                  WHERE ID_DISTRIBUZIONE = BASE.ID_DISTRIBUZIONE AND ID_DIPENDENTE = @ID_DIP_DEST
             )
```

to populate `#Temp` with the data you are inserting into `DOC_LISTE_DISTRIBUZIONE`. You should then be able to do:

```
INSERT INTO DOC_LISTE_DISTRIBUZIONE
    (ID_LISTA,ID_DISTRIBUZIONE,ID_DIPENDENTE,NRO_COPIE,TIPO_DISTRIBUZIONE,NOTE)
    SELECT ID_LISTA_INC + @ID_LISTA, ID_DISTRIBUZIONE,ID_DIPENDENTE, ... FROM #Temp

SELECT @ID_LISTA = @ID_LISTA + max(ID_LISTA_INC) FROM #Temp

UPDATE SW9_SEQUENCES
    SET LAST_ID = @ID_LISTA
    WHERE SEQ_NAME = 'DOCN_ID_LISTA_DISTRIBUZIONE'
```

Comment: Thanks, i was just replying to the first question that i need a cursor for managing a non identity column while you wrote this. It makes sense and i will try it.

Comment: After trying fAST_FORWARD (as sugggested by dean) i was amazed: from 45 to 3 seconds. So this time I will use FAST_FORWARD, next time i will go for your temp table approach. Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem; I wasn't aware of `FAST_FORWARD` either, I'll have to read up on it myself. Would be interested in the speed increase of my solution, if you do have time to try it.